# JavaScript animation wrong "pos" variable of an element with each iteration

Tags: javascript, html, css

What exactly is the logical error in the following JavaScript for animation of an element containing a cloud image? I think the "pos" variable seems to be way off with each iteration and I can't figure out how with each iteration the motion of the cloud image grows more and more frenzied.

```
//CSS:
#container{
               background-color : #defffc;
               width : 100%;
               height : 100%;
               position : relative;
            }

#clouds{
            position : absolute;
            width : 300px;
            height : 200px;
            opacity : 0.3;
        }

//Body: 
<p><button type = "button" onclick = "animateCloud()">Move Cloud</button></p>
    <div id = "container">
        <div id = "cloudy">
            <img src ="cloudy.png" id = "clouds"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

//Script: 
<script>
        function animateCloud(){
            var pos = 0;
            var cloudElement = document.getElementById("clouds");
            var id = setInterval(motion, 5);

            function motion(){
                if(pos==1000){
                    //clearInterval(id);
                    id = setInterval(remotion, 5, pos);
                }
                else{
                        pos++;
                        cloudElement.style.left = pos + 'px';
                        cloudElement.style.right = pos + 'px';
                    }
                }

                function remotion(){
                alert(pos);
                    if(pos==0){
                            id = setInterval(motion, 5, pos);
                    }
                    else{
                            pos--;
                            cloudElement.style.right = pos + 'px';
                            cloudElement.style.left = pos + 'px';
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `setInterval` you are telling the JavaScript to repeat that function every n milliseconds, so having intervals calling functions that create more intervals is actually calling your position changes more frequently.

I suggest you look at [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) over [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to make sure you aren't repeatedly creating more intervals.

Edit: after taking another look at your code, keep the [clearInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and remember to put it into your `remotion` base case as well; otherwise you'll start to exponentially create more intervals like I mentioned above.